# Using ObjectType global variable in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sobject

In the doc (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm) it is said that the SobjectType global variable can be used in lightning component, but when i wrote it like stated , I am obtaining an error :

```
{!$ObjectType['Account'].fields['MaisonMereRecherche__c'].Label}
```

where MaisonMereRecherche is my custom field on the account object.

I obtained the following error :

```
Result: [ERROR]: expecting a positive integer, found ''Account'' at column 13 of expression: $ObjectType['Account'].fields['MaisonMereRecherche__c'].Label: Source
```

When I tried rewriting it like i used to do in VF like this :

```
 $ObjectType.Account.fields.MaisonMereRecherche__c.Label
```

I have no error, but it is not showing on my page.

What am I missing here ? Note that i'm coding on the latest API version (38.0)

Comment: I checked the doc link there's no mention of SobjecType being supported in Lightning component.

Comment: Meaning it is confirmed that i can't use the ObjectType global variable in lightning components ? Is their a way to use it in lightning controller or helper also???

Comment: I think it's not possible for now.

Answer (score 2):

Ligthning expressions are not the same as visual force expressions.

the list of global value providers are described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm)

Lightning expression support arrow braces only for accessing arrays, so there expected the integer index